# Error "listed is not defined" in a Python class

Tags: python, class

Why do I get the error `listed is not defined` in the following code snippet?

```
import socket,select
from threading import *
import time

neighbours=[]
def neighbourfuncall():
    print('In neighbours')

class pyserver(Thread):
    dictn={}
    HOST=socket.gethostname()
    PORT=8888
    buf=1024
    ADDR=(HOST,PORT)
    listed=[]
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(ADDR)    
    sock.listen(30)

    def __init__(self):
        self.interval=6
        listed.append(sock)
        thread=threading.Thread(target=neighbourfuncall,args=())
        thread.daemon=True
        thread.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            sel,out,spl=select.select(listed,[],[],15.0)
            for s in sel:
                if s==sock:
                    client,address=sock.accept()
                    listed.append(client)
                    dest=client.recv(buf)
                    dictn[client]=dest      
                else:
                    pass

serv=pyserver()  
serv.run()
```

Comment: Why do I get the error--'listed' is not defined when I have already defined it as a class variable? The above code is just a brief of a server that I intend to build.....I only have issues regarding the instantiation...

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok...so if am to initialise an empty list then it has to be done directly inside the --init--() ?

Comment: No... I didn't know that you wanted them to be class variables. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: But I see it done here--http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-and-object-vars.html

Comment: Yeah, correct. I did not know that you wanted them to be class variables.

Comment: @BhargavRao ok...I wanted to have a common list for my class....But it keeps showing the error when I tried to compile...

Comment: Why are you trying to play with _threads_ and _sockets_ if you don't even know the basics? This is not the best way of learning.

Comment: @Rinzler Thanks for helping out....Hadn't noticed that part....you don't realize mistakes without making one....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access `listed` with the following syntax:

```
pyserver.listed = ["I need to study more Python!"]
```

since it's a static class variable.

Answer (score 1):

As you're in a class, you need to use `self.list.append(smth)`. All class variables must be accessed using `self`.

By the way, socket operations must be in `__init__()`. You'd better do this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.smth=socket()
    self.other=[]
    self.smth.DoSomething()
def Hello(self):
    self.other.append("Hello") #just example
```